# HBASE Installation - Getting ZOOKEPER RELATED ERROR

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am able goto the hbase prompt but when i try to create table getting below error:

```
ERROR zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher: hconnection Received unexpected KeeperException, re-throwing exception
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1041)
```

I have below code in `hbase-site.xml`

```
<configuration>enter code here
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>file:///usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
<value>/usr/lib/hbase/zookeeper</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

not sure why IP address of my VM has changed, like it was `192.268.211.xyz`, changed that incremented last value.

If any one have clear steps on how to install Hbase on Hadoop in VM (Ubuntu), please do share the same with me.

Answer (score 1):

Hbase Configuration:

edit you `hbase-site.xml`:

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>hdfs://your_ip_address:54310/hbase</value>
</property> 

<property>
   <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
   <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
   <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>  
   <value>your_ip_address</value>
</property>

<property>   
  <name>dfs.replication</name>   
  <value>1</value>    
</property>

 <property>       
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>  
  <value>2181</value>                                                                                 
 </property>

 <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/hbase/zookeeper</value>   
 </property>
```